# Do not detect changes while runing project

Tags: intellij-idea

I add changes to my java project in `Intelij IDEA` and run project. Application is running with no changes. If I want run app with changes I must rebuild project before every run and it is annoing.

I try:

1. VCS -> Refresh File Status
2. File -> Synchronize
3. File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

All actions do not help. Any idea?

Comment: What kind of project (for example plain Java application, Web app, ...)? What kind of run configuration (for example local tomcat)? Which IDEA version? Note also that there is a difference between "Build" and "Rebuild": The main menu "Build" contains menu items "Build Project" and "Rebuild Project" which do different things. Is a simple "Build" enough to see your changes? Do you "Run" or "Debug" you project?

Comment: It was java desktop application. Using Intellij IDEA 2016.3 and it is Maven build. `Run` or `Debug` do not help. I solved it, read my answer below ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

There was problem in Intellij IDEA cache. I deleted `.idea` cache folder, next imported project and it is working now.